# Dynamics x 2012 SSRS report, cant find DP class in Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, report, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I don't understand why I couldn't find my DP class in Visual Studio when I was adding a dataset to SSRS report. Then I copyied a standard SalesInvoiceDP class, I couldn't see it either. I can see DP class in the AOT in Visual Studio, but I can't find it when adding dataset.

Anyone can help me with this ? Thanks in advance !!!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Data provider class is used specifically to fill the tmp table that u used in ur query, why do you need it in the Visual studio at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that happened to me as well. I have a test and live enviroment. The Visual Studio reads the current Ax configuration in your client. If you are working on the Test Environment, then you must set the right tcpip port (probably different from 2712) and the right WSDL port (probably different from 8101). Do that and open the report directly from the AOT, that worked for me, Hope it helps

Cris